# Unable to import child from parent package python

Tags: python, package

I'm currently writing a web application in python that needs unit tests, however whenever I try to import a child module that's in another parent directory I get the following error:

```
$ python my_package/tests/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_package/tests/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from my_package.core.main import hello
ImportError: No module named my_package.core.main
```

### File: my_package/core/main.py

```
hello = "Hello"
```

### File: my_package/test/test.py

```
from my_package.core.main import hello

print(hello, "world!")
```

### My directory structure:

```
$ tree
. 
└── my_package
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── core
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── main.py
    └── tests
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test.py
```

Could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is **[considered an anti-pattern](https://github.com/amontalenti/elements-of-python-style#avoid-syspath-hacks)** to modify `sys.path`. If you want your package to be available to all subpackages, it's better to use `setup.py` development mode.
Create `setup.py` in the root of your project:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="you_project",
    version="0.0.0",
    packages=['my_package', ],
    install_requires=['requirement1', 'requirement2'],
)
```

Then run:

`$python setup.py develop`

After this you will be able to import `my_packege` from anywhere within your Python environment.

Comment: Or run `pip install -e .`.

Answer (score 0):

Your my_package is not in PYTHONPATH. At the top of your test.py add the below. Note that any change in location of test.py would affect package_path

```
from os.path import dirname, abspath
import sys
package_path = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(package_path)
```

Comment: Turns out I had to mark the package as my sources root in my editor, but this worked too. Thanks, I'll accept in a few

Comment: It is common to have something such as `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))` in the main file of your project, to make it location-independent.